# How to connect from cakePHP3 to MSSQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, windows-server-2012-r2

(I develop on a Windows System with XAMPP and use cakePHP3)

I want to connect from my cakePHP3 Localhost application, to a external SQL Server (installed on a external Windows Server 2012 r2).
In my `app.php` I config my Server and that is how I test the connection:

```
  try {
      $connection = ConnectionManager::get('sqlServer');
      $connected = $connection->connect();
      }catch (Exception $connectionError) {
      echo "not";
      }
      echo "connected";
```

On testing I get this error:

> A Database connection using was missing or unable to connect. 
>   The database server returned this error: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

So I go to my Server and Installed the needed extensions (ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server). But I get still the same Error.

Is it possible to connect to the external Server from Localhost? Or did I make a mistake?

Comment: You need drivers to communicate php with you database even its on the localhost or at server. Check this link https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php

Comment: I solve this. The Server blocked all of my requests